# Configuration for the Sugar connector to DocuSign not working

Tags: sugarcrm, docusignapi

I've installed the latest W-Systems DocuSign module for SugarCRM and I followed the installation guide to the T (https://www.w-systems.com/media/DocuSign/SugarConnectortoDocuSign_InstallationUseGuide.pdf). However, my problem start at the end of page 7 where I click "Configure DocuSign" or "DocuSign User Settings > Log In". Nothing happens.. no error message, no dialog window, nada.

I've run "Rebuild JS Grouping Files", "Quick Repair and Rebuild", cleared the cache and tried multiple browsers.

Has somebody else encountered this problem? Any suggestions on how to solve it?

**EDIT**: I was able to use the module without problems on a co-workers machine, but I still cannot use it on my own.

Comment: Did you check the logs of Sugar? If they contain nothing useful, set the log level to `info` or `debug`, then reproduce the problem and check the logs again. Also you could check the webserver/php-logs for potential problems.
Is the connector free to download? If you post me the link and the exact version of Sugar, MySQL and PHP being used, I or somebody else could try to reproduce the problem and have a look.

Comment: It seems you had the right idea @Jay, looking at the debug logs revealed some problems. I provided an answer describing the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being in contact with W-Systems support, they found out (by looking at the debug logs) that the database tables hadn't been correctly set up. The problem was fixed by uninstalling the module (without removing the tables), reinstalling the module, Admin > Quick Repair and Rebuild, and finally hard refresh (for me Ctrl+F5).

Everything now runs normally.

Answer (score 1):

The SugarCRM <-> DocuSign Connector is written and maintained by SugarCRM, not DocuSign. The only integrations (Connectors) that DocuSign implements and maintains are its integrations with Microsoft, Google, and Salesforce.

With that said, if you're running into bugs/issues with the connector you'll need to contact SugarCRM and go through their support to resolve.